# Writing a JUnit test for a "Step" scoped bean - No scope registered for scope name "step" (Spring Batch 3.0.10)

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-batch, spring-test

I want to write a JUnit test case for a `Spring` managed bean which has the scope as "step". This bean is refereed by  a Spring Batch Tasklet.

**Bean defintion for configDAO ConfigDAOImpl class**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- bean has been defined with a scope of "step" as it uses the stepExecutionContext -->
    <bean id="configDAO"
        class="com.myproject.common.dataaccess.impl.ConfigDAOImpl" scope="step">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="${threadpool.size}"/>
        <property name="frequency" value="#{stepExecutionContext['frequency']}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**JUnit test case for the above bean**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/common.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring/common-context.xml" })
public class ConfigDAOImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigDAOImpl configDAO;

    @Spy
    private ContextParamDAO contextParamDAO = new ContextParamDAOImpl();

    private static final String SCHEMA_CONFIG = "classpath:data/CONFIG_SCHEMA.sql";
    private static final String DATA_CONFIG = "classpath:data/CONFIG_DATA.sql";

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        DataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript(SCHEMA_CONFIG)
                .addScript(DATA_CONFIG)
                .build();

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        //override the jdbcTemplate for the test case    
        configDAO.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        configDAO.setContextParamDAO(contextParamDAO);


    }

    //.. more coode
}
```

When I run the above test class, it fails with the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'step'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

I tired added @EnableBatchProcessing annotation above my test class but that did not resolve the issue.

How can I write a JUnit test for a `step` scoped bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find more information in the official documentation, there's a section called ["Testing Step-Scoped Components"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testingIndividualSteps). But for a start you should annotate your Test with these two annotations (pre Spring 4.1) enabling your step scope.

```
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
```

Or this annotation, for Spring 4.1+

```
@SpringBatchTest
```

You then also need to define a StepExecution, similar to this (and taken from the documentation)

```
public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().putString("input.data", "foo,bar,spam");
        return execution;
    }
```

Comment: I am going to go ahead and accept this answer since this seems like the official way to resolve the issue. However, this did not work for me so I will be posting a new question to understand why.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114625/junit-test-for-a-step-scoped-bean-using-stepscopetestexecutionlistener-class-s/61120766#61120766 if you are interested in knowing how I managed to finally fix the issue.