# JUnit test for a Step scoped Bean using StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class : Still getting "No Scope registered"

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-batch, spring-test

I am trying to write an independent unit test case for a "step" scoped bean. I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099235/writing-a-junit-test-for-a-step-scoped-bean-no-scope-registered-for-scope-na) earlier and understand that I need to use a `StepScopeTestExecutionListener` to create a step scope for my unit test; however, I still get the following exception even after using the `StepScopeTestExecutionListener` :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'step'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

**My JUnt**

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class,DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class  })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/common.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring/common-context.xml" })
public class ConfigDAOImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigDAOImpl configDAO;

    @Spy
    private ContextParamDAO contextParamDAO = new ContextParamDAOImpl();

    private static final String SCHEMA_CONFIG = "classpath:data/CONFIG_SCHEMA.sql";
    private static final String DATA_CONFIG = "classpath:data/CONFIG_DATA.sql";

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        DataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript(SCHEMA_CONFIG)
                .addScript(DATA_CONFIG)
                .build();

        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        //override the jdbcTemplate for the test case    
        configDAO.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        configDAO.setContextParamDAO(contextParamDAO);


    }

    public StepExecution getStepExecution() {

        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        jobParametersBuilder.addString("test", "test");
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters();

        JobInstance jobInstance = new JobInstance(12345L,"testJob");
        JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution(jobInstance,jobParameters);

        StepExecution execution = 
        MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution(jobExecution,"step",11245L);
        execution.getExecutionContext().putString("input.data", "foo,bar,spam");
        return execution;
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the `getStepExecution` does get called as I ran the unit test in debug mode with a  breakpoint on this method.

**Question : Why is the step scope still not getting initialized for my JUnit?**

**Note:** On an unrelated  note, the reason why I am manually creating a `JobExecution` inside  `getStepExecution` instead of using `MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution` is because for some weird reason, the compiler is able to find the `createJobExecution` method but the method is not found at runtime. I used the `-verbose:class` flag and can confirm that there is only one jar from where the `MetaDataInstanceFactory` class gets loaded and that jar contains the required method as well. I am assuming that manually creating a `JobExecution` instance should not be the root cause of my issue.

Comment: Where is you step scoped bean defined? In `/spring/common-context.xml` ? Is the scope "Step" defined in that context?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yes that's right. The bean is defined as  `<bean id="configDAO" class="com.myproject.common.dataaccess.impl.ConfigDAOImpl" scope="step">`. I also provided the contents of the `common-context.xml` in the linked question. Also note that I am using Spring Batch 3.0.10 and Spring batch test 2.2. I can't updgrade to a newer version because of budget constraints.

Comment: ok thanks. I added an answer with the required details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens **before** even loading your test, since there is no step scope bean defined in your `common-context.xml` file. Since you are not using the batch namespace in that file, you need to declare the step scope manually. Here is an excerpt from the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope) (of 3.0.10):

```
Because it is not part of the Spring container by default, 
the scope must be added explicitly, either by using the batch namespace
or by including a bean definition explicitly for the StepScope (but not both)
```

Adding the following to your application context should fix the issue:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
   <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. In your answer, you also mention that I can use the batch namespace. What does that mean?

Comment: glad it helped. Spring Batch provides an XML namespace `xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"` that you can use to define jobs, steps, etc. There is an example in the link to the docs I added in my answer.

Comment: I do use the batch namespace in my `common-context.xml` so I am wondering why I still need to create a `StepScope` bean manually in the XML.